# Inheritance not working

Tags: java

From my code I want my bedroom class to inherit length and breadth from the superclass - room. I have filled the errors in the respective lines within comments.
I am getting errors and I can't find my way out. Help me please?

```
package index;

public class Room {
int length;
int breadth;

Room(int x,int y)
{
    length = x;
    breadth = y;
}
int area(){
    return (length*breadth);
}
}

class BedRoom extends Room{      //Implicit super constructor Room() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
    int height;
    public void Bedroom(int x,int y,int z)
    {
        super(x,y);    //Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor
        height=z;
    }


int volume(){
    return (length*breadth*height);
    }
}
class InherTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BedRoom room1 = new BedRoom(14,12,10); //The constructor BedRoom(int, int, int) is undefined
        int area1 = room1.area();
        int volume1 = room1.volume();
        System.out.println("Area1 = "+area1);
        System.out.println("Volume1 = "+volume1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your BedRoom class has a ***pseudo-constructor*** not a real constructor. Constructors don't return anything, not void not anything.  Get rid of that void statement.

Change

```
public void Bedroom(int x,int y,int z)
```

to

```
public BedRoom(int x,int y,int z) // also capitalize correctly
```

Answer (score 8):

You have simply misspelled `BedRoom` as `Bedroom` in the constructor declaration. (Correcting this would give you a more simple-to-understand error message about the problem that @HovercraftFullOfEels mentions: constructors do not have a return type.)

Comment: 1+ as I missed the capitalization bit, that you caught.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: And the same to you, for the converse reason :-)

Comment: Change "public void Bedroom(int x,int y,int z) ..." with "public BedRoom(int x,int y,int z) ...".

Answer (score 2):

- Constructors' name must match class name, but since Java is case-sensitive `Bedroom` is not valid name for constructor in `BedRoom` class.
- Also constructors doesn't have return type so remove `void` from it.

In other words replace

```
public void Bedroom(int x, int y, int z) {
//     ^^^^    ^
```

with

```
public BedRoom(int x, int y, int z) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
 public void BedRoom(int x,int y,int z)
```

As for java Bedroom is not same as BedRoom